# Finding number of smaller elements for each element in an array efficiently

Tags: algorithms, arrays, permutations

I am stuck on this problem:

> Given an array $A$ of the first $n$ natural numbers randomly permuted, an array $B$ is 
>   constructed, such that
>   $B(k)$ is the number of elements from $A(1)$ to $A(k-1)$ which are smaller than $A(k)$.
>
> i) Given $A$ can you find $B$ in $O(n)$ time?
>   ii) Given $B$ can you find $A$ in $O(n)$ time?

Here, $B(1) = 0$. For a concrete example:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
  A & 8 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 6 & 5 \\
  B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I found this: [Computing permutation encodings](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/26789/1/postscript.pdf) which gives $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ algorithms for these problems. At least I think they are the same problems.

Comment: @Merbs does that Hint you gave mean that you have a solution ?

Comment: @AJed, it means I have an algorithm, though it takes $O(n^2)$ for the simple algorithm without space and $O(n\log n)$ if we are allowed space. At the moment, I'm leaning towards neither being not possible in $O(n)$ and both being the same algorithm.

Comment: @Merbs. I feel your hint can lead to the right track. i m having one solution too (following your hint). I guess there is a trick in the analysis that makes it go to $O(n)$.. I think the trick is the knowledge that $A$ goes from 1:$n$ only.

Comment: [Another paper that talks about this](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-96-1.pdf): "One way of defining  the inversion table is :
given a permutation of n integers $\left\{ a_1, a_2 ... a_n \right\}$ from the ordered set $\left\{ 1, 2 ... n \right\}$,  its inversion
table $\left\{ b_1, b_2 ... b_n \right\}$ is obtained by letting $b_j$ be the number of elements to the left of  element $j$ that are greater than $j$."

Comment: ... "Example 4 :
the permutation   5  6  1  3  2  4  8  7   has the inversion table  2  3  2  2  0  0  1  0,
because to the left of element 1 there are two elements, 5 and 6, to the left of element 2
there are three elements, 5, 6 and 3 and so on. Notice that other simple definitions are
possible, such as counting all the elements on the right of j, or using less than instead of
greater than for the comparison. By this definition the last value  must always be  0,
therefore only n - 1 components of the generated vector are meaningful."

Comment: This paper also gives a $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ algorithm. Are you sure there exists an $\mathcal O(n)$ algorithm for this?

Comment: This was asked to one of my friends in an interview. I am not sure whether the solution exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

The naive algorithm for determining $B$ from $A$:

> For $k=1,\dots,n$, determine the value of $B(k)$ by comparing each $A(i)$ to $A(k)$ for 
>   $i=1,\dots,k$ and counting those that satisfy $A(i)<A(k)$.

This algorithm compares $A(1)$ to all others ($n-1$ times), $A(2)$ to $n-2$ others, etc. so the total number of comparisons is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$. But that's not the best we can do. For example, looking at $B(n)$, we don't have to do any comparisons! $B(n)=A(n)-1$ because it's the *first* $n$ natural numbers, and it’s guaranteed (regardless of the permutation) that the $n-1$ lower natural numbers will be there. What about $B(n-1)$? Instead of checking $A(1)$ through $A(n-2)$, we could just check $A(n)$. That is:

> For $k=1, \dots,\frac{n}{2}$, use the algorithm above; for
>   $k=\frac{n}{2},\dots,n$ use the reverse algorithm: determine $B(k)$ by
>   setting it initially to $A(n)-1$ and then subtracting $1$ for each
>   entry $A(i)$ for $i=k+1,\dots,n$ that is less than $A(k)$.

This would take $2\times\frac{(\frac{n}{2}-1) (\frac{n}{2}-2)}{2}=\frac{(n-2)(n-4)}{4}$ steps, which is still $O(n^2)$. Note also that in constructing $A$ from $B$, if $B(n)=A(n)-1$ then $A(n)=B(n)+1$.

But now for more finesse. If we’re allowed some additional space or sort in-place, we can sort the numbers as we’re comparing them. For example:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
  A & 8 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 6 & 5 \\
  S & 9 & 8 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 5 \\
  B & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 6 &  &  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Instead of checking all of them (or checking them in order), we could use binary search to determine each $B(k)$. However, the sorting still takes time $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: This was just my first idea; though I realize the problem is more interesting than I originally gave it credit. And I haven't had an opportunity yet to read Realz Slaw's findings, so the algorithm may be off.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than determining each $B(k)$ one at a time, we can be forward looking and only go through each number in $A$ *once*! But we'll use $n$ space:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
  A & & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & & B \\
  8 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & & 0\\
  4 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & & 0\\
  3 & & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & & 0\\
  1 & & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4 & & 0\\
  7 & & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & \color{red}{3} & 4 & 5 & & 3\\
  2 & & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & & 1\\
  9 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 5 & \color{red}{6} & & 6\\
  6 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \color{red}{4} & 5 & 6 & 7 & & 4\\ 
  5 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \color{red}{4} & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & & 4\\ 
\end{vmatrix}$$

We could save even more time by not updating those that have already been determined (that is, there is no point in updating $8$ after the first step), but in the worst case, we still have to update $\frac{(n)(n+2)}{2}$ times

Answer (score 0):

both I and II are solvable using #next_greater_element that i explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84795/for-each-i-find-minimal-ji-such-that-ajai/84851#84851). but its a little harder than just the problem but before solution you need to learn next greater element:

1. consider we have a vector for every element of $A$ name it $S_i$ for
   element $i$. now once run the next greater algorithm starting from
   right to left but except setting element $i$ in $A$ its next greater
   element index , push in $S_i$ the elements that $i$ is their next
   greater element.then iterate over the array left to right and then
   $B[i]=\sum_{j=0}^x (S_i[j]+1)$ where $x$ is the size of vector
   $S_i$.and its $\Theta(n)$ because each the next greater algorithm is $\Theta(n)$ 
   and also iterating is $\Theta(n)$

second part is also similar noting that we can get the value of the rightest element in $O(1)$
EDIT:my solution is wrong  it seems that it dont have any$o(n)$ solution