# For each $i$, find minimal $j>i$ such that $A[j]>A[i]$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arrays

I have the following problem:

> Given an array $A$, I need to construct an array $B$ such that $B[i]$ is the minimum $j>i$ such that $A[j]>A[i]$, or Null if no such $j$ exists.
>
> For example, if $A = [23,45,13,10,33]$ then $B = [2,Null,5,5,Null]$.
>
> The algorithm should run in time $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please put more effort into writing your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , I've corrected the question

Comment: Nice problem! What are your thoughts on it? Can you think of *any* algorithm at all?

Comment: I thought about to start from the end of array A (index n) and go to index 1 . Create additional array in order to store elements I already checked. But I'm not sure regarding Θ(n) complexity.

Comment: Your formulation didn't match your example, so I changed it – it seems that you want the minimal index $j > i$ such that $A[j] > A[i]$ (you missed the condition $j > i$).

Comment: What's the context where you encountered the problem?  I encourage you to cite/credit the original source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its next greater element problem
its solvable using stack 
u can learn it from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/) (in method 2)
for more practice of this useful method u can solve these problems:

Largest Rectangle
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/largest-rectangle/

And xor Or
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/and-xor-or

Poisonous Plants
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/poisonous-plants

196A - Codeforces
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/196/A

319B - Codeforces
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/319/B

Minimum Sum
http://agc005.contest.atcoder.jp/tasks/agc005_b

these are solvable using #next_greater_element

Comment: Can you perhaps include the solution using a stack, in your own words? Links could rot, and we prefer answers here to depend on them only to the extent necessary.